# Reformat string containing date and time to date only in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have a string in this format: "Sat Sep 19 15:18:51 2015"

I would like to reformat it to "20150919"  I have spent the last few hours reading Python documentation and Q/As relating to this on this web site, but I'm still stuck.  I could do it with slicing and string manipulation, but I'm looking for a better way to accomplish the goal.  A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format is persistent, you can use the python [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
input = "Sat Sep 19 15:18:51 2015"
# See if you can replace parse_format string with "%c"
parse_format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"
output_format = "%Y%m%d"
datetimeobj = datetime.strptime(input, parse_format)
output = datetimeobj.strftime(output_format)
print output
```